# jest - mock function returns not a function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to mock a function using jest but I got an error on code where mock is called `TypeError: got is not a function`.

In my implementation, I've something like:

```
const got = require('got')
got('...', {})
```

And I've wrote mock function as:

```
jest.mock('got', (url, options) => {
  console.log('on my way', url)
  return 1
})
```

The message `on my way` is printed but I got the error mentioned. I'm pretty sure that the problem is the way I wrote mock.

Any help on how to mock `got()`?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to `jest.mock` should be a module factory function that returns the mock.

You just need to wrap your mock in a factory function that returns it:

```
jest.mock('got', () => {
  return (url, options) => {
    console.log('on my way', url)
    return 1
  }
});
```

Comment: Very cool, didn't know about the module factory function and had to look it up! Here's the doc: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-docs-en-jest-object-jestmockmodulename-factory-options-with-the-module-factory-parameter